# Javascript - How to split a string into a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I know I can use `split` function to transform a string to an array but how can a string be split twice to produce a nested array?

I expected this would be sufficent but it does not produce the desired output.

```
var myString = "A,B,C,D|1,2,3,4|w,x,y,z|"
var item = myString.split("|");
var array = [item.split(",")];
```

Would it be more optimal to use a for each loop?

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
var array = [
  ["A","B","C","D"],
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["w","x","y","z"],
];
```

Comment: I mean, it would certainly be workier since the current code makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've split on `|`, use `.map` to account for the nesting before calling `.split` again. There's also an empty space after the last `|`, so to exclude that, filter by `Boolean` first:

```js
const myString = "A,B,C,D|1,2,3,4|w,x,y,z|";
const arr = myString
  .split('|')
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(substr => substr.split(','));
console.log(arr);
```

Or you could use a regular expression to match anything but a `|`:

```js
const myString = "A,B,C,D|1,2,3,4|w,x,y,z|";
const arr = myString
  .match(/[^|]+/g)
  .map(substr => substr.split(','));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myString = "A,B,C,D|1,2,3,4|w,x,y,z"
var item = myString.split("|");

var outputArr = item.map(elem => elem.split(","));
console.log(outputArr);
```

Comment: Why map if you’re just going to use it to iterate?

Comment: oops. I saw that. I have't edit the answer before I post. Thank you. I wll update